# Initialize javascript Object literal property Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to define the input values from HTML page as javascript Literal object property but i am getting **Undefined** error on accessing in JS file.

Suppose i have a input value like as in HTML

> <input type="hidden" id="someid" value="dbvalues in arrayform" >

Now this value i am trying to define like (A.js) as below:

```
var abc = {
  x : $("#someid").val(),
  y: function (){
     console.log(this.x);
  }
}
```

Now when in another JS file (B.js) i call it as

> console.log(abc.x());

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.js

```
var abc;
$(function() {
    abc = {
        x: $("#someid").val(),
        y: function (){
            console.log(this.x);
        }
    }
});
```

B.js

```
$(function() {
    abc.y();
});
```

Note that `$("#someid").val()` will return a string, so you may need to convert into into an array.

Comment: You are asking `question` as `answer`

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not function, it is `string`.

You should call it as:

```
console.log(abc.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

two things - first of all it would not be `console.log(abc.x());`  `x()` is how you call a function, you could call `abc.y()`; though since it's a function.

the other thing is that jQuery must be loaded, and that this code defining `var abc = {`  has to be executed after the DOM is fully loaded

I think you want this:

```
$(function(){  // this ensures DOM is ready, careful about where you want to call abc from though;
    var abc = {
      var me = this;
      x : function(){ return $("#someid").val()},
      y: function (){
         console.log(me.x);  // try this instead it will help with 'this' confusion
      }
    }
});
```

now you can call

`console.log(abc.x());`

Comment: `var abc = {
      var me = this;` is invalid syntax

Comment: and ur solution has two errors... first as mentioned by @RobM. and secondly console statement will return function as it is because it is never executed...